# Is it possible to declare a multidimensional array using enumerated indexes?

Tags: arrays, go, enums, slice

I want to define a two dimension array or slice in Go and use enumerated values to access the data in the array.  The following will not compile and I am hoping that you can help me to figure out how to make it work.

```
type (
    Color  int
    Fruit  int
    MyType [][]string
)

const (
    Red  Color = 1
    Blue Color = 2

    Apple     Fruit = 1
    BlueBerry Fruit = 2
)

func DoIt() {
    produce := make([][]MyType, 0)
  
    // COMPILE ERROR: "Yummy Apple"' (type string) cannot be represented by the type MyType
    produce[Red][Apple] = "Yummy Apple"
}
```

Comment: Hi Cerise, Thank you for your quick response.  After posting, I saw the index issue and corrected it.  The posting shows the change...  At this time, my real code is using a map of maps, which seems like overkill for something that a 2D array or slice can provide.  Any ideas about the compilation error that I posted in my update would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to declare an array of arrays using enumerated indexes.

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    type (
        Color int
        Fruit int
    )
    
    const (
        Red      Color = 1
        Blue     Color = 2
        NumColor       = 3
    
        Apple     Fruit = 1
        BlueBerry Fruit = 2
        NumFruit        = 3
    )
    
    func main() {
        var produce [NumFruit][NumColor]string
        produce[Red][Apple] = "Yummy Apple"
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", produce)
    }
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AxwcxLE3iJX

Answer (score 1):

Remove MyType from declaration. Then it will work.

```
type (
    Color int
    Fruit int
)

const (
    Red  Color = 1
    Blue Color = 2

    Apple     Fruit = 1
    BlueBerry Fruit = 2
)

func DoIt() {
    produce := make([][]string, 0)

    produce[Red][Apple] = "Yummy Apple"
}
```

Comment: You can also use `map[Color]map[Fruit]string` for this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Shahriar!  My original code was based on a map..map, as you suggested.  I was trying to find something that mapped more directly into what I was doing with the enumerated values, which is what lead me to the 2D array.  Unfortunately, when I tried to run the code with your suggestion, it failed on the assignment: "panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 0".  The allocation in the code needs to include the array length, like: produce := new([2][2]string).  This change makes the code similar to Billingham's example and it works, too.